# UIToolbar not showing UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ipad, uitoolbar

I'm using a storyboard and I've a split view where the master is a UITableViewController. Like the iPad Mail app, I'd like to display a UIToolbar.

I wasn't able to add the toolbar via storyboard but I managed to add it programmatically. I'm also able to add a UILabel to the toolbar, but I can't find a way to add a refresh button or any kind of UIBarButtonItem.

Any idea?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 0.0f, 80.0f, 40.0f)];
  label.text = @"last updated...";
  label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
  [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:label];

  UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(action:)];
  UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action:)];

  NSArray *buttons = @[item1, item2, nil];
  [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to the Apple iOS Forum!

When you use the toolbar of the navigation controller, you have to set the toolbar buttons on the **active** view controller's `toolbarItems` property, not on the actual navigation controller's toolbar itself.

From the [`UINavigationController` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller#1654291):

> **Displaying a Toolbar**
>
> A navigation controller object manages an optional toolbar in its view
>   hierarchy. When displayed, this toolbar obtains its current set of
>   items from the `toolbarItems` property of the active view controller.
>   When the active view controller changes, the navigation controller
>   updates the toolbar items to match the new view controller, animating
>   the new items into position when appropriate.

For example:

```
[self setToolbarItems:buttons animated:NO];
```